# Git binary vs. -diff in .gitattributes

Tags: git

In .gitattributes are the following equivalent:

```
*.chm binary

*.chm -diff
```

I have tried `*.chm` binary but I am afraid it may still try to merge these files. Is `-diff` more appropriate for what I intend to do ?

Also, will this setting be applicable after a file of the given type has already been committed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for your question, you asked:

> I have tried `*.chm` binary but I am afraid it may still try to merge these files. Is `-diff` more appropriate for what I intend to do ?

The built-in macro attribute *binary* is equivalent to:

```
[attr]binary -diff -merge -text
```

(ref: *[Defining Macro Attributes - Gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_macro_attributes)*)

So from your question being afraid that `-diff`  over `binary` may be more appropriate: It is not that much of a difference. Both should normally suffice, the *gitattributes* documentation names `-diff` as one of the easiest ways to mark a file as binary. So why not go with it for `.chm` files?

See the following example which shows the effect of some of the attributes in your question:

```
.gitattributes file
[1]                     | [2]                   | [3]
------------------------|-----------------------|------------------------
*.chm binary            | *.chm -diff           | *.chm binary
*.chm -diff             |                       |

$ git check-attr -a help.chm
------------------------|-----------------------|------------------------
help.chm: binary: set   | help.chm: diff: unset | help.chm: binary: set
help.chm: diff: unset   |                       | help.chm: diff: unset
help.chm: merge: unset  |                       | help.chm: merge: unset
help.chm: text: unset   |                       | help.chm: text: unset
```

> ***REMARK:*** `[1]` above is identical in output to the single-line `*.chm -diff binary` or `*.chm binary -diff`. A strong hint that all these are logically equivalent to just `*.chm binary` and *different* to `*.chm -diff`.

For the question if `-diff` is *more* appropriate for your intend, it depends on the other *gitattributes* in your configuration and which you deem appropriate or not. As you have not shared them in your question, I could consider them undefined for the answer (no offence here, attributes can be either set, unset or undefined). But then the answer would not be complete. So anything is possible and using the *binary* marco-attribute may unset or define a previously already set or undefined *merge* and/or *text* attribute being already effective in a repository configuration.

Therefore `binary` looks preferable over `-diff` to me only for pressing an answer (not likely good) as you are concerned about merging binary files and it is the `binary` macro attribute that unsets the `merge` attribute with the following consequences:

> **Unset**
>
> Take the version from the current branch as the tentative merge result, and declare that the merge has conflicts. This is suitable for binary files that do not have a well-defined merge semantics.

(ref: *[`merge` - Performing a three-way merge - Gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_merge)*)

This is the same as using the *binary* built-in merge driver. So like the *binary* macro-attribute suggests, you mark the merge explicitly as "binary".

In difference to `-diff` - which also implicitly marks the file as binary - the *binary* macro-attribute **does** change the *merge* attribute and therefore unsetting the *diff* attribute allows to have a different than the unset *merge* attribute merge driver in action (this is where the existing answer is correct, using `binary` is not the same as `-diff` - it was incomplete listing the attributes of the macro thought and missed the unset of the *merge* attribute - it may not have been documented for the version in use thought, maybe git version < 1.7.12.4).

As you perhaps can imagine these are pretty fine details. In short `-diff` should suffice, `binary` may not hurt, but unsets more attributes than normally necessary and therefore is more explicit on the merge (not mentioning the *text* attribute), but may have unwanted side-effects and/or make some future maintenance harder (this is pretty theoretical, however it might do that little more which made you afraid in the first place).

My personal answer is, don't be afraid and follow your own preference for `-diff` until you run into a practical problem. Most likely you have solved this already long-time ago.

---

Also thanks for the additional question you asked:

> Also, will this setting be applicable after a file of the given type has already been committed ?

Yes.

When in doubt try it out with `$GIT_DIR/info/attributes` (which has the highest precedence) as it is local to your clone and is never committed, then verify with `git check-attr` how it affects the attributes of already committed files.

Git does not store the attributes in the repository per each committed file, only in the `.gitattributes` file/s if it/they is/are committed.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.  `binary` is a built-in *macro attribute* and means `-diff -text`.  See [the MACRO ATTRIBUTES section of the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_using_macro_attributes) for details.