# How to mark a file as not binary in git?

Tags: git

I had some files in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) (a git-based online editor) that had certain characters that made the files look binary.  Once the git files are binary, they are not editable online in Overleaf.  I took out those characters, so the files should be straight text, but the files are still not editable in Overleaf, probably because git is still treating them as binary.

How do I mark them as "not binary" so I can edit them in Overleaf again?

**EDIT**: Hmm, maybe there is no way, because revisions have binary characters.

Comment: All characters are binary. This must not ruin the day if Overleaf is not overreaching.

Comment: Files are just streams of bytes. It's up to the consumer to decide if those bytes represent a text encoding or not.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Are you using an encoding other than UTF-8, such as UTF-16?

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue for Overleaf, but it normally works with the `.gitattributes`  and there is a `binary` macro so you can use it:

```
file.ext -binary
```

More special interest references:

- [Git binary vs. -diff in .gitattributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58918555/367456)
- [Can git's .gitattributes treat all files as binary except a few exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4264447/367456)